# I need to check for an API call if it returns a response within 90 seconds

Tags: c#

I need to monitor the below method to make an API call if it returns a response within 90 seconds.

```
var response = await _testAPI.GetResponse("test_input_string");
```

Comment: Does it provide an overload that takes a `CancellationToken`? Do you have control over the API, so you could add an overload that takes a CancellationToken?

Comment: ^^ "it" = `_tstAPI.GetResponse(string)`

Comment: Fildor - I don't have the control

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var responseTask = _testAPI.GetResponse("test_input_string");
if (await Task.WhenAny(responseTask, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90))) == responseTask)
{
   // Got response before 90 seconds. Call API.
}
```